# Dive 24 hour day in 48 slots

Tags: java, time

I have divide the 24 hour day in to 48 time slots. So I hardcoded it like this:
(java code)

```
private static void createMap() {
    timeSlotMap.put(0, "0:30");

    timeSlotMap.put(1, "01:00");
    timeSlotMap.put(2, "01:30");

    timeSlotMap.put(3, "02:00");
    timeSlotMap.put(4, "02:30");
    ...
    ...
    timeSlotMap.put(45, "23:00");
    timeSlotMap.put(46, "23:30");

    timeSlotMap.put(47, "24:00");
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Something like a loop with some kind of [time unit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

Comment: Yeah, but what happens when you hit daylight savings time :-)...

Comment: What kind of time slot is 24:00?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way using [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html):

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT;
int minutesToAdd = 30;
Map<Integer, String> times = new TreeMap<>();

for(int i = 1; i < 48; i++){
    times.put(i - 1,time.plusMinutes(minutesToAdd * i).toString());
}

times.put(47, "24:00");
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there is, that's what loops are for. Make the first argument the loop index, and construct the second one from the first, for example, with the [String.format](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples) function:

```
        private static void createMap() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
                int t = (i + 1) * 30;
                timeSlotMap.put(i, String.format("%02d:%02d", t / 60, t % 60));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!